# The command '/bin/sh -c yum install yum-utils' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, yum

i am trying to setup laravel php setup using docker.
Is something wrong with the docker file or the network configurations !!!!
Using **DockerFile**:

```
FROM centos:7

# Install some must-haves
RUN yum -y install vim wget sendmail
RUN yum -y install libtool make automake autoconf nasm libpng-static
RUN yum -y install git
RUN git --version

# Install PHP 7.1 on CentOS
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
    && rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum install yum-utils
RUN yum install epel-release
RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73

RUN yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 -y install php php-bcmath php-cli php-common php-gd php-intl php-ldap php-mbstring \
    php-mysqlnd php-pear php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc php-zip php-fpm

RUN php -v

# Prepare PHP environment
COPY config/php/php-fpm.conf /etc/php-fpm.conf
COPY config/php/www.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY config/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY config/php/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
RUN composer --version

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
RUN yum -y install nodejs
RUN yum list installed nodejs
RUN node -v

# Final update and clean up
RUN yum -y update --skip-broken
RUN yum clean all

# Define work directory
WORKDIR /var/www/laravel-boilerplate

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm", "-F", "-O"]
# CMD ["/bin/sh", "-l", "-c", "php-fpm"]
# CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]
```

Command which i had run to setup the instances are,

```
docker-compose up -d
```

any idea what went wrong?

**Adding docker compose file**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel_boilerplate
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
  laravel-env:
    build: ./dockerfiles
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/laravel-boilerplate"
      - "./dockerfiles/config/php/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php-fpm.conf"
      - "./dockerfiles/config/php/www.conf:/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf"
      - "./dockerfiles/config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini"
      - "./dockerfiles/config/php/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - laravel-env
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/laravel-boilerplate"
      - "./dockerfiles/config/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
```

Let me know if I missed anything!!!!

Is something has to get removed while building or is something had to deleted like cleanup, am pretty new setting up the code so. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks folks.

Comment: mind to share with us docker-compose.yml file too please?

Comment: What's the actual error?  Can you reduce this to a [mcve]; if nothing after `RUN yum install yum-utils` runs, can you delete that, and if packages like `vim` and `git` aren't necessary to reproduce the issue can you delete those too?  Can you directly use the Docker Hub `php` image rather than recreating it?

Comment: @Facty added compose file too.

Comment: hmm not much coming on my mind but I would try `RUN yum -y update` before any package install

Comment: Even this error out with ERROR: Service 'laravel-env' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y update' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Should i need to change the upstream URL anywhere?